# Minify .master page file

Tags: asp.net, minify, master-pages

Is there any online tool out there that will minify (remove white space, comments) from a .master page file.  I am trying to improve the performance of my site.

Comment: [This package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.WebForms/) might be of assistance

Comment: I am not sure but magnifying .master page is not going to help you much.

Comment: I am not sure but magnifying .master page is not going to help you much.